# Can File.Exists throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-2.2), `File.Exists` method does not generate exceptions:

> Returns true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.

So it sounds like it doesn't throw exceptions on its own.  But can a call to `File.Exists` result in an exception?  In other words, do I need to wrap it in a try/catch?

Comment: Try it out. Put in some invalid paths.

Comment: Yes.  The user may not have the credentials to check if the file exists.

Comment: @jdweng Would that not fall under "If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown" in the quoted documentation?

Comment: according to the documentation, no exception is thrown, here is the documentation link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=netcore-2.2

Comment: The user could have permission to read the folder , but not the permission to read the files.

Comment: `String[] paths = null; System.IO.File.Exists(paths.First());`

Comment: @15ee8f99-57ff-4f92-890c-b56153 Then `.First()` call on a null reference would be the cause of the exception, not the call to `File.Exists`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, according to the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/File.cs):

```
    // Tests whether a file exists. The result is true if the file
    // given by the specified path exists; otherwise, the result is
    // false.  Note that if path describes a directory,
    // Exists will return true.
    public static bool Exists(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            if (path == null)
                return false;
            if (path.Length == 0)
                return false;

            path = Path.GetFullPath(path);

            // After normalizing, check whether path ends in directory separator.
            // Otherwise, FillAttributeInfo removes it and we may return a false positive.
            // GetFullPath should never return null
            Debug.Assert(path != null, "File.Exists: GetFullPath returned null");
            if (path.Length > 0 && PathInternal.IsDirectorySeparator(path[path.Length - 1]))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return FileSystem.FileExists(path);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException) { }
        catch (IOException) { }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }

        return false;
    }
```

There isn't seem to be any case the it should throw an Exception unless `FileSystem.FileExists` throws some exception I don't know about.

EDIT: Since I cannot find out source code of `FileSystem.FileExists`, I checked the [.NET Framework source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,f6a0a4f50ba5376e) instead, it's a bit different at the internal call:

```
    // Determine whether path describes an existing directory
    // on disk, avoiding security checks.
    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    internal static bool InternalExists(String path, out int lastError) {
        Win32Native.WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA data = new Win32Native.WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA();
        lastError = File.FillAttributeInfo(path, ref data, false, true);

        return (lastError == 0) && (data.fileAttributes != -1)
                && ((data.fileAttributes & Win32Native.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0);
    }
```

It in turn calls `FillAttributeInfo` (the code is a bit long so I don't paste it here), I think it only throws `IOException` (at line 1402 `__Error.WinIOError();`)

Comment: What if the FileSystem.FileExists(path) results in a regular `Exception`?  Wouldn't it blow up?

Comment: @AngryHacker: yes it will, although formally a regular "exception" should not be raised. More likely it will blow up at memory issues. To be sure if there are no others, all calling functions should be analyzed. Although one might assume, since it's documented, they are covered by actual test cases.

Comment: @AngryHacker Sorry I can't really find the source code of `FileSystem.FileExists` so I am not sure but assuming from the list of `catch`es, I think those are all the Exceptions. As Stefan noted, it's more likely some low-level exception (like `OutOfMemoryException`) than normal ones.

Comment: @LukeVo `FileSystem.FileExists` is defined in [`FileSystem.Exists.Unix.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/b60e3c347d0af66dc7f7788b736be7f5315c3ad1/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Exists.Unix.cs#L36) and [`FileSystem.Windows.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/af2e995a851fe0d218b8c9d17e08b0802150b102/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/FileSystem.Windows.cs#L274).  Aside from a call to `Debug.Assert()` no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: @BACON wow thanks for tracking it down, I came across `FileSystem.Windows.cs` somehow but skipped it, as it wasn't in the source browser.

Comment: @LukeVo But it can still results in an OOM because there is an allocation `path = Path.GetFullPath(path);` , correct?

Comment: @AngryHacker yes, everything can result in `OutOfMemoryException` (or in rarer case, `StackOverflowException`), but you can't really try-catch them as usual (more details in the other answers)

Answer (score 5):

**Everything** can result in a Exception. Even if the code itself does not throw one, what if you run into a Fatal Exception like OutOfMemory or ThreadAborted?

This sounds like it is primarily a question about Exception handling, and for those questions I have two articles that I link often:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

If you want to learn how to deal with exceptions, they are a very good start.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I encountered this Exception :

**System.IO.PathTooLongException:** 'The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.'

The Exception came from Path.GetFileName that File.Exists was calling.

Comment: [This is only true for .NET 4.6.1 or before](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=net-7.0#remarks). In [.NET 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-7.0) for example: "The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file."

Answer (score 0):

There are no exceptions listed in the documentation for that method, which implies no exceptions should be thrown. In fact, further down it mentions that "false" will be returned if an exception would have been thrown trying to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can raise exceptions.

E.g.: [OutOfMemoryException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception?view=netframework-4.8).

These kind of exception might not be thrown by the code itself, but might be thrown as a side effect of executing it.

The same woud apply for the infamous StackOverflowException, or also, more low level exceptions maybe due to failing hardware.

I am unaware of the total listing; but I am sure; calling the code *can* lead to exceptions being raised.

As @Otis notes: it will be difficult to recover from those kind of exceptions. So, even if they are raised: often a try/catch will not be sufficient.

So, to sum it:

> can a call to File.Exists result in an exception?

Yes

> In other words, do I need to wrap it in a try/catch?

Another question, but, presumably not.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the kind of exception you can try/catch your way out of.

Comment: @Otis that is another quesiton altogether. Wich is why I directly linked my favourite articles. They have helped a lot of people.

Comment: @Otis According to the linked article, it appears that you can.  Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @AngryHacker: no, there are always tons of exceptions that can happen beyond the scope of the .net framework. They will be low level and you wont be able to catch them. If memory corruption is involved,  your application might just exit even with maximum tty catch blocks. In worst case youll get the famous bluescreen on windows. Now, the method itself would not likely be causing this, but the call can trigger it; and you will not recover by catching exceptions. Dont believe me: try xamarin with android sdk ;-)